# Should I reconfirm an interview I already accepted via email?

Tags: interviewing, applications

I have already been emailed the time of the interview. And confirmed via email.

They sent me this email where I can select if I will go, or not, or maybe. I selected Yes. Then I simultaneously received a text message stating the details of my interview again.

Should I reply? If yes, via text or email?

Comment: Who on this planet is accepting "maybe" as a reply to "We want to interview you, do you attend?"

Comment: Did you get the text immediately after responding to the E-Mail? If so, it seems to me that the text is a confirmation of the interview details from the employer and wouldn't require a reply. If you received the text before replying to the e-mail go with the two answers here for sure.

Comment: @nvoigt My guess is that it was an Outlook appointment or something similar, where the options "yes","no" and "maybe" are programmed and you can chose whichever you want.

Comment: Wait some time for a confirmation email to come back, if none do then call and confirm.

Answer (score 2):

> Then I simultaneously received a text message stating the details of my interview again. Should I reply? If yes, via text or email?

Yes.

There's no harm in replying twice. And if you chose not to reply to the text, there's a very slight possibility that someone on the other end might be confused.

Unless the message indicates otherwise, reply using the medium in which the request was sent. In this case, reply via text.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

They want to confirm if you are going to attend the interview. I imagine they "simultaneously" send both email and text, and you just happened to read and reply via email first.

Less likely scenario is to confirm your contact details and preference.

Answer (score -1):

I'm interested in working for places that want to interact with me, not send me messages of convenience.  I get more out of talking to somebody that information from an email or text.

It seems to be you are trying to either:

1. Be courteous
2. Be complete
3. Follow social norms
4. Make certain you get the interview

The best way to address all of these is to call.  If you have a phone number, pick up the phone and contact whomever sent you the message.  You'll learn (x10) as much from a phone call and some interaction than you will from an email or a text message.

My time is too valuable to be treated like a cog in a gear and provide and automatic reply via email / text.  If they want to hire me and I want to work for them, we're going to have to interact.  A voice on the phone is the next best thing to being there in person to judge whether you want to work for them or not.